# execute if function in a timed loop

Tags: time

I have a school project where I had to make a piece of code work for 1 minute and then return. I first used a RFID reader which didn't work for me so I decided to use the serial monitor. I did this through a switch function and if it was the correct number you had 1 minute to push in the buttons.

But now to the problem for me is that in the timed loop I made it can't look for if functions and because of that I can't look if the buttons are pressed. 
I hope it was a 
clear explanation and someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Pasted code can be formatted correctly by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button in the question editor (or pressing Control+K).

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me. But I think you should actually read the switches via `digitalRead()` inside the loop.

Comment: Why did you again removed your pasted code, that I formatted for you?

Comment: Because the code had no spaces or next lines and thus wasn't readable. I also had no idea how to change it to make it look readable. But your comment about digitalRead() was very helpful, I had a digitalRead() for my buttons but I had put it in a different loop but now that I moved the digitalRead() to the Right() it work now. So thank you very much.

Comment: Normally, a timed loop is a bad design in Arduino projects. Rather use the given void loop() function and non-blocking functions inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chrisl mentions,  you should use `digitalRead`. 
Assign this to the correct variables:

```
switchState1 = digitalRead(…) // Fill in the correct pin here
switchState2 = digitalRead(…) // Fill in the correct pin here
```

Also, you can separate the first part of the `if`, so you get:

```
if (switchState1 == HIGH)
{
    if (switchState2 == HIGH)
    { 
        digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    }
    else if (switchState2 == LOW)
    {
        digitalWrite(2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    }
}
```

Since the inner condition only depends on switchState2 and the pins are equal, you can write:

```
if (switchState1 == HIGH)
{
    digitalWrite(2, switchState2 == HIGH);
    digitalWrite(3, switchState2 == HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4, switchState2 == HIGH);
}
```

And you can use instead of the switchState2 a switchState2High (Boolean), and only check it when switchState 1 == HIGH.

```
if (switchState1 == HIGH)
{
    switchState2High = (digitalReadState(…) == HIGH);
    digitalWrite(2, switchState2High);
    digitalWrite(3, switchState2High);
    digitalWrite(4, switchState2High);
}
```

You also could use a for loop for the last part so you get:

```
if (switchState1 == HIGH)
{
    switchState2High = (digitalReadState(…) == HIGH);
    for (int pin = 2; pin < 5; pin++)
    {
        digitalWrite(pin, switchState2High);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works now so thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: You are welcome / good luck with your project